# how to add just an background image and a link button in android application?

Tags: android, eclipse, image, background, hyperlink

I am completely new with Android and Eclipse.

I just want to create an application. I am trying to set a background image (App Logo views in that image and some texts will be in it) and want to make a button that links to my website.

How can set background image and how can i send the user to my website by clicking that dummy buttons?

Thanks you all. Best wishes...

Answer (score 2):

This the xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnViewWebsite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
        android:text="Visit Website" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the activity set the onClick action of the activity. In which you can use this

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Also In the place where @null is written, pass the image. @drawable/some_image

Make sure to add Internet Permission in `manifest.xml` file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: No problem, If it worked I would ask you to mark it accepted as it will help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Create an activity and add code-

```
final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            view.loadUrl("http://myweb.in");
        }
    });
```

and create an xml with code-

```
 <Button 
   android:id="@+id/button"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Go To Web"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

 <WebView 
   android:id="@+id/web"
   android:layout_below="@+id/button"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

hope this work..

Answer (score 0):

in xml:

```
 android:background="@drawable/imgname"
```

in java:

```
_ImageView1.setImageResource(resId);//resId  R.Drawable.imgname
```